# Проброс результата через закрытую активити

Tags: java, android, android-intent, activity-life-cycle

Имеется три активити, скажем Activity1, Activity2 и Activity3. Задача стоит в том, чтобы получить результат с помощью setResult из третьей активити Activity3, при условии что вторая активити закрывается после открытия из нее третьей.

Из первой переходим во вторую:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2 .class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Из второй переходим в третью, и закрываем ее:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity3 .class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
finish();
```

В третьей пытаемся по некоему событию передать код RESULT_OK и вернутся к первой:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

Но в первой в переопределенном методе `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` получаем, что requestCode = 1, а вот resultCode не RESULT_OK, а ноль... Есть ли какой то способ прокинуть результат с условием закрытия промежуточной активити?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно несколько вариантов предложить:

1. Не закрывать 2 `Activity` после `startActivityForResult(intent, 1);`, а делать это в `onActivityResult`. Т.е. такая схема:

   1А -> 2A -> 3A -> 2А `onActivityResult`(здесь ловим результат и перебрасываем на 1, закрывая ее) -> 1А
2. Запускать 1 `Activity` из 3 и в `intent` складывать нужную информацию. В таком случае, в манифесте можете указать `android:launchMode="singleTask"`, дабы `Activity` выводилась на передний план, а не создавалась новая.
3. Перевести на фрагменты.
4. Изменить логику, дабы избежать такой необходимости.

Comment: Да, благодарю, думаю стоит остановится на первом вашем предложении, вполне жизнеспособное решение